# Reading Google Sheets in distributed Python application

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth

I am working on an application that is going to be distributed to multiple people. One of the things this application needs to do is to read certain Google spreadsheets, however, I have read that to be able to read google spreadsheets via API you must authenticate with your Google account.

People this application is intended for might not have a Google account, or might not be willing to enter their Google email and password into the program.

Is there a way to be able to read Google Sheets without entering your private Google credentials? Perhaps some sort of a public account that will be only used for the application? Or maybe there is a case where you don't need to have an account whatsoever?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I am planning to use `gspread` library, but if there is a better option in my case, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use a Web App

This is not the only option open to you, but it may be the simplest to get started with. You can effectively host what seems to be an endpoint that you can make GET and POST requests to. If you set it to, the underlying script runs as if it was you running it. When you deploy it as a web app, all you need to do is set "Who has access to the app" as "Anyone, even anonymous".

Some sample code for an Apps Script web app. The GET returns simple HTML, and the POST, if the structure of the request is correct, will update a spreadsheet with the info and send an email to the address provided from your account:

```js
function doGet() {
    textOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello World! Welcome to the web app.")
    return textOutput
}

function doPost (e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() // works if container bound
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
  
  var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
    return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
  })
  
  var newRange = sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length)
  newRange.setValues([newRow])
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter["email"], "Hello", "Welcome");
}
```

#### References

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Apps Script Main Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Sheets Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [Sheets Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)